# my app is killed by jetsam but reason is "compressor-space"

Tags: ios

When I run app in iOS 13.1.2 on iPhone9,2, but my app often killed by system by jetsam.

Who knows why app is killed by jetsam. 
Thank you very much.

`{"bug_type":"298","timestamp":"2019-11-13 20:05:00.09 +0800","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)","incident_id":"97D144D0-3495-424F-B45A-502066FB0B08"}`

```
{
  "crashReporterKey" : "8d7ba6fa31a92416cffdf487733e67c10bc9a4b3",
  "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Tue Sep  3 21:52:11 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.2.3~2\/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010",
  "product" : "iPhone9,2",
  "incident" : "97D144D0-3495-424F-B45A-502066FB0B08",
  "date" : "2019-11-13 20:05:00.09 +0800",
  "build" : "iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)",
  "timeDelta" : 42,
  "memoryStatus" : {
  "compressorSize" : 83073,
  "compressions" : 4635112,
  "decompressions" : 2887266,
  "zoneMapCap" : 1146650624,
  "largestZone" : "kalloc.368",
  "largestZoneSize" : 11250128,
  "pageSize" : 16384,
  "uncompressed" : 220487,
  "zoneMapSize" : 118980608,
  "memoryPages" : {
    "active" : 33975,
    "throttled" : 0,
    "fileBacked" : 47623,
    "wired" : 23622,
    "anonymous" : 20189,
    "purgeable" : 14,
    "inactive" : 32130,
    "free" : 9527,
    "speculative" : 1707
  }
},
```

```
 "largestProcess" : "myAppName",
  "genCounter" : 20,
  "processes" : [
  {
    "uuid" : "db8635d3-79a3-3e1a-8621-5576220161a9",
    "states" : [
      "daemon"
    ],
    "killDelta" : 2817,
    "genCount" : 0,
    "age" : 1040217040,
    "purgeable" : 0,
    "fds" : 50,
    "coalition" : 3069,
    "rpages" : 8930,
    "reason" : "compressor-space",
    "pid" : 10658,
    "cpuTime" : 7.335655,
    "name" : "myAppName",
    "lifetimeMax" : 8931
  },
```

```
  {
    "uuid" : "ff9f855f-f412-3bbb-a2ac-3ec22d6e2769",
    "states" : [
      "daemon"
    ],
    "killDelta" : 166934,
    "lifetimeMax" : 100,
    "age" : 99403921053,
    "purgeable" : 0,
    "fds" : 50,
    "genCount" : 1,
    "coalition" : 513,
    "rpages" : 95,
    "reason" : "compressor-space",
    "pid" : 9992,
    "idleDelta" : 924917926,
    "name" : "companion_proxy",
    "cpuTime" : 0.068721000000000004
  },
```

{
    "uuid" : "53bd7768-d403-3c02-b111-f6ad67d4c5ff",
    "states" : [
      "daemon"
    ],
    "killDelta" : 181779,
    "lifetimeMax" : 75,
    "age" : 99403826027,
    "purgeable" : 0,
    "fds" : 50,
    "genCount" : 2,
    "coalition" : 516,
    "rpages" : 71,
    "reason" : "compressor-space",
    "pid" : 9993,
    "idleDelta" : 938805754,
    "name" : "notification_proxy",
    "cpuTime" : 0.15176899999999999
  },

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-high-memory-use-with-jetsam-event-reports) The reason key identify the jettisoned process and why the system jettisoned it. Only the jettisoned process has the reason key.

I cant find reason "compressor-space" in the docs, maybe as the question is old, this reason got deprecated.

Reasons for whoever is still interested:

- per-process-limit: The process crossed the resident memory limit imposed by the system on all apps. Crossing this limit makes the process eligible for termination. If the process is an app extension from your app, note that extensions have a much lower per-process memory limit than foreground apps. Carefully consider your needs before using technologies with a high-baseline memory cost, such as SpriteKit or a MKMapView, in an extension point. Alternate solutions may be more appropriate. For example, an image created by MKMapSnapshotter has lower memory use than a MKMapView, and is a better choice for many extension-point scenarios.
- vm-pageshortage: The system experienced memory pressure and needed to free background process memory for the current foreground app.
- vnode-limit: Too many files were open across the system. The kernel has a finite number of vnodes, a memory structure backing open files, and these were almost exhausted. To avoid terminating the frontmost app when vnodes are nearly exhausted, the system may terminate your app in the background to free vnodes, even if your app isn’t the source of excess vnode use.
- highwater: A system daemon exceeded its highest-expected memory footprint.
- fc-thrashing: A process thrashed the system file cache. This occurs when non-sequential parts of memory-mapped files are read and written too frequently. To avoid terminating the frontmost app, the system may terminate your app in the background to free space in the file cache, even if your app isn’t thrashing the file cache.
- jettisoned: The system jettisoned the process for some other reason.

Comment: Thank you for the summary! For the benefit of others, the ‘reason’ `vm-compressor-space-shortage` ~still~ appears as recently as iPadOS 15.x *(at least with some ‘jetsam’ reports involving Mobile Safari)*.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: See also the definitions inside of `kern_memorystatus.h`, especially: *(`kMemorystatusKilledVMCompressorSpaceShortage` = `JETSAM_REASON_MEMORY_VMCOMPRESSOR_SPACE_SHORTAGE`)* and *(`memorystatus_kill_cause_name[] =` … `"vm-compressor-space-shortage"` `/* kMemorystatusKilledVMCompressorSpaceShortage */`)*


Reference: [Learn more about oom (low memory crash) in iOS] *( https://programmer.ink/think/learn-more-about-oom-low-memory-crash-in-ios.html )*

Answer (score 0):

##### Background

AFAIK, `JetsamEvent` rarely kills the *frontmost* app.

Apps in the background are liable to be killed at any time, and even if yours is *perfectly behaved*, an excessive demand for memory elsewhere on the may still cause it to go.

- The less RAM a process holds on to in the background, the less likely it will be closed for this reason.

If memory is low, backgrounded apps are ranked in terms of recent activity and memory usage. The ones with the *least recent* activity and the *highest memory usage* are prime targets for purging to minimize impact on user activity. *(I imagine this exact ranking algorithm has evolved over the years.)*

- The ‘reasons’ discussed *(in [Mahmoud’s answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69538550))* mostly just note which part of that algorithm selected a particular process for closure.

---

##### Answer

**`compressor-space` may be an older name for what is now *(in 2022)* logged as: `vm-compressor-space-shortage`**

`vm-compressor-space-shortage` is the `memorystatus_kill_cause_name` *(for logging purposes only, so that string is unlikely to be found in most of the source code)* for:

- `kMemorystatusKilledVMCompressorSpaceShortage` *and*
- `JETSAM_REASON_MEMORY_VMCOMPRESSOR_SPACE_SHORTAGE`

Since iOS doesn’t use ‘swap’ space for its virtual memory system, it compresses inactive memory instead. *(On macOS or Linux, this same sort of error would be called something like “Process killed due to low VM swap space”.)*

Depending on how ‘compressible’ the contents of inactive memory currently are, it’s *really* hard to forecast how much will be available in advance. *(That could be why this is a separate ‘reason’ than `vm-pageshortage`??)*

---

##### Reference

See also the definitions inside of `kern_memorystatus.h`, especially:

- `kMemorystatusKilledVMCompressorSpaceShortage` = `JETSAM_REASON_MEMORY_VMCOMPRESSOR_SPACE_SHORTAGE`
- `memorystatus_kill_cause_name[] =` … `"vm-compressor-space-shortage"`

  - `/* kMemorystatusKilledVMCompressorSpaceShortage   */`

An interesting technical discussion / investigation into how this all works in certain scenarios: [Learn more about oom (low memory crash) in iOS](https://programmer.ink/think/learn-more-about-oom-low-memory-crash-in-ios.html)